# Sharepoint 2013 | Direct link from List Item to Document Set

Tags: list, sharepoint, set, document

I need a **direct link** from a list item lookup column (other column types might be correct I am not sure) to a document set.

At the moment a dialog opens and then I have to click open to then send me to the document set. This doesn't feel very cohesive and isn't the best for the user experience.

I have a custom list of 'solutions' and want to link to the relevant document sets.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Associated Documents' column should be a hyperlink/picture column, which will allow you to directly launch to whatever your URL is without a dialog.